# awk parse error on '<' operator

Tags: awk, parse-error

I'm trying to make an alias in .alias file for tcsh.
Alias is something like this :

```
alias do "grep -iE '<pattern>' <file> | awk '{if($2 < 0)print}'"
```

When i try to run the alias it give me following error :

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {if( < 0.0) print}
awk: cmd. line:1:      ^ parse error
```

Any idea why this would happen ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try. You need to escape the single quotes and don't use any double quotes.

```
alias do 'grep -iE '\''pattern'\'' filename | awk '\''{if ( $2 < 0 ) print}'\'''
```

Comment: @zobars: It is generally considered polite to "accept" the answer that worked best for you.  And to vote it up.

Comment: @JUST, I'm all with you..sorry i'm new here so it took me a while to figure out how to accept the answer and I tried but don't have enough reputation to upvote yet.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the bit about not being able to upvote.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to start with the command line you provide is gibberish:

```
$ alias do "grep -iE '' | awk '{if($2 < 0)print}'"
bash: alias: do: not found
bash: alias: grep -iE '' | awk '{if( < 0)print}': not found
```

If I correct it to what I think you mean, I see this:

```
$ alias do="grep -iE '' | awk '{if($2 < 0)print}'"
$ alias do
alias do='grep -iE '\'''\'' | awk '\''{if( < 0)print}'\'''
```

And with this we can see why you're getting a parse error.  The $2 is being eaten by the shell before `awk` ever sees it.  Try this instead:

```
$ alias do="grep -iE '' | awk '{if(\$2 < 0)print}'"
$ alias do
alias do='grep -iE '\'''\'' | awk '\''{if($2 < 0)print}'\'''
```

My guess is that at this point you won't be getting your parse errors any longer.  (I can't speak for the rest of this, naturally, since I don't know what you're using as input.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes i've made it up as the real example is really long. The problem is i tried escaping $2 just like you suggested and it still is being eaten by the shell... the problem is with $2, i just tried and changed if($2 <0) to if($ < 0), for sake of testing and when i do that $ is not eaten but $2 is.... Any ideas ??

Comment: The `=` is Bash (and Bourne-family) syntax and some of your quoting may be dependent on characteristics of those shells. The OP is using `tcsh` which may have slightly different quoting rules (and doesn't use `=` when defining an alias.

Comment: @Dennis: Ah!  I hadn't caught the `tcsh` thing at the beginning.  My apologies.  @zobars: Whatever the issue is, it will be related to quoting rules of your shell.  If `tcsh` allows you to see the literal stored value like `bash` does, look and see what `tcsh` actually thinks the alias is.